# Many to Many Relationship Query Where Records Do Not Exist

Tags: mysql

here's a great challenge for you!

We're trying to create a query for a many to many database, there are many clients and many orders, the records table being the joint table. We need to select all the rows from the Orders table where the clientid equals the specified id e.g. 1, 2 or 10 etc where also there is no record for that order.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.0.1
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Oct 09, 2020 at 10:14 AM
-- Server version: 10.4.11-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 7.3.15

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `lb`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `clients`
--

CREATE TABLE `clients` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `clientname` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dumping data for table `clients`
--

INSERT INTO `clients` (`id`, `clientname`) VALUES
(1, 'john'),
(2, 'sue');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `links`
--

CREATE TABLE `links` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `linkname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `da` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dumping data for table `links`
--

INSERT INTO `links` (`id`, `linkname`, `da`) VALUES
(1, 'ice cream', 0),
(2, 'pizza', 0),
(3, 'pasta', 0);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `records`
--

CREATE TABLE `records` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `linkid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `clientid` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dumping data for table `records`
--

INSERT INTO `records` (`id`, `date`, `linkid`, `clientid`) VALUES
(1, NULL, 2, 1),
(2, NULL, 2, 2);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `clients`
--
ALTER TABLE `clients`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `links`
--
ALTER TABLE `links`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `records`
--
ALTER TABLE `records`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `linkindex` (`linkid`),
  ADD KEY `clientindex` (`clientid`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `clients`
--
ALTER TABLE `clients`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `links`
--
ALTER TABLE `links`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=54;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `records`
--
ALTER TABLE `records`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `records`
--
ALTER TABLE `records`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `records_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`clientid`) REFERENCES `clients` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `records_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`linkid`) REFERENCES `links` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;


SELECT links.id, links.linkname
FROM links
LEFT JOIN records ON records.linkid = links.id
WHERE records.linkid IS NULL AND records.clientid != 1
```

The desired output is a list of all the orders for example Sue hasn't placed,

Sue (ID 2) has placed an order for Pizza, so the result of the query should show only Pasta and Ice Cream

```
id linkname
 1 ice cream
 3 pasta
```

We expected this to work but seems like We've missed something!

Thank you in advance for any exceptional problem solving skills!

Comment: Replace short tables definitions with complete CREATE TABLE scripts. Provide some sample data as INSERT INTO scripts and show desired result for this data.

Comment: Change WHERE to AND

Comment: and Change AND to WHERE

Comment: @Akina thank you so much for your comment - I hope I've added everything you need and it makes more sense now :)

Comment: @Strawberry thanks strawberry, I tried swapping the WHERE with AND however it generated 0 results, I've added more info now, I hope this helps - thanks again

Comment: 1) I do not see desired output for provided data as an output table. 2) Your script is incorrect. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=77882b534d05695fc2ec0f21bd0b5d88). Edit it until workable, adjust MySQL version, and provide the link.

Comment: @Akina, sorry for that Akina - I've added the whole dump now all working, please see the desired output also. Thanks again :)

Comment: Works fine for me https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rwADHotaESSaNnQ5CWpgXJ/2

Comment: Thank you @Strawberry you're right it does work that way! However.. I'm not sure our idea how to generate the result is correct. Do you have any ideas what the best way to get a list of all the orders which a client hasn't placed?
```
SELECT links.id, links.linkname, records.clientid, records.linkid FROM links LEFT JOIN records ON records.linkid = links.id AND records.clientid != 2 WHERE records.linkid IS NULL
!= 2 doesn't really select the client...
```
How do we select the clients orders which haven't been placed in the records table which doesn't yet contain the record?

Comment: Please amend your question to provide the desired result.